# use vimdiff with a diff file

Tags: vim, vimdiff

How can I use vimdiff to view the differences described in a diff file?

Comment: I [reported a feature request](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3552).

Answer (score 58):

Instead of using `/usr/bin/vimdiff` command, try this:

```
$ vim file
:vertical diffpatch path/to/diff
```

(`:vert diffpa` for short.)
This is equivalent to calling `vimdiff` on the original file and the subsequently patched file, but `vim` calls `patch` on a temporary file for you.

### Edit

If you want `vim`'s diff-mode to be entered automatically, use this:

```
$ vim file +'vert diffpa path/to/diff'
```

where `+command` asks `vim` to execute "command".  (`+123` jumps to line 123, `+/abc` jumps to  the first match for "abc", it's all documented.)

Regarding Ken's query: if the diff file includes hunks applying to files other than the file you're currently editing, no worries; `vim` calls the `patch` executable underneath, which will ask for the locations of these mysteriously missing files, and you can tell `patch` to just skip those hunks.

Comment: nice! But you should maybe warn about the risk of side-effects if the file contains diffs for other files?

Comment: That works great for a single file. Thanks! I didn't know about diffpatch.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to save the diff file to disk?  Something like: `:vert diffpatch - !git diff file`?  (I know there are better solutions for `git diff` specifically, but I'm curious if this is possible in general)

Answer (score 3):

Coming from the other direction. I wrote a Vim plugin that shows the changes that have been made to a file since the last save in either vimdiff or unified diff format.

Get it here: [diffchanges.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2158)

Comment: I think it's better to save early, save often and use Gundo: http://sjl.bitbucket.org/gundo.vim/ instead.

Answer (score 2):

Make a copy of the original file, apply the diff and then

```
vimdiff original_file patched_file
```

You could also look at [vim.org scripts](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2090) which have been written to deal with svn diff output. If you are generating your diff from a version control system then take a look at the  [vcscommand.vim : CVS/SVN/SVK/git integration plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90).

Answer (score 1):

Would you say more about why you want to use vimdiff for this?

For instance, do you want to [visualize per-character differences in a (unified) diff file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231759/how-can-i-visualize-per-character-differences-in-a-unified-diff-file). If so, someone answered [my question about same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231759/how-can-i-visualize-per-character-differences-in-a-unified-diff-file) with [a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231759/how-can-i-visualize-per-character-differences-in-a-unified-diff-file/3509992#3509992) to basically just fire up emacs on the diff and hit `ALT-n` to cycle through hunks, nicely highlighting per-word or per-characters changes along the way (similar to vimdiff). It works well, but it's a bummer to fire up emacs just to do this. I only know enough emacs to do that then exit without mucking up the patch. :)

Anyway, the emacs answer gave me some ideas. I'm sure Vim can be cajoled into providing better highlighting for diff files, maybe something more like ediff. I looked into this a while back, and someone on the vim user list had the excellent suggestion to [incorporate google-diff-match-patch](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim/89542/focus=91342). The Python interface could be used from a Python Vim ftplugin, for instance.

Sorry about using an "answer" to reply when this may not be a great answer, the formatting for "add comment" was too limited for what I wanted to say.

For posterity, [here's a reference to another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704707/viewing-unified-diff-with-meld-vimdiff-other-tools) (which already links here as well).