# A visual patch tool for Linux

Tags: linux, user-interface, diff, patch

I've got a file and a patch for it. I'd like to visually apply the patch, t.i. see how the changes proposed by the patch look in context, make some corrections, and save the resulting file.

What tool can do that?

Neither of the visual diff tools (i.e. meld, diffuse, diffmerge) do what I want: they don't work with patches, they merely merge whole files.

Comment: Hey Euguene, what did you end up selecting and how did it work for you?

Answer (score 27):

I really like **Kompare**. It is just a (very nice) graphical interface for diff.

http://www.caffeinated.me.uk/kompare/

sudo apt-get install kompare

> **Creating and applying patches**
>
> Kompare is able to create a patch file
>   which lists only the differences
>   between two compared text files A and
>   B. Further, Kompare can apply a patch
>   file which was created this way to an
>   original file A and, in this manner,
>   recompute the contents of the
>   corresponding file B. This is a
>   comfortable utility for passing a
>   corrected version of a file to a
>   friend who already has an older
>   version of the same file, because only
>   the (relatively small) patch file has
>   to be delivered and the receiver can
>   generate the corrected file by
>   applying the patch to the original
>   file.
>
> The patches created and applied by
>   Kompare are compatible to patch files
>   generated or applied by the command
>   line interface diff utility, because
>   Kompare is in fact merely a graphical
>   front end to diff and the patches are
>   created and applied by patch, which
>   gets called by Kompare.

Comment: YAY! Kompare is a really nifty tool. I usually use GNOME, so the KDE deps put me off using it until now, but it's absolutely worth it. The only thing it lacks is Meld/TortoiseDiff's highlighting of differences in the scroll margin, but I can always use Meld for that.

Comment: Yep. Totally worth it, even for a GNOME user, imo. :)

Comment: KOMPARE Website down.   Alternative info site: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kompare

Comment: Dunno, just installed it and tried to open a `svn diff` output. Got this: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=252359

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use it to apply a patch produced by relative diff. There was no way to choose the folder to apply it too.

Answer (score 18):

See [use vimdiff with a diff file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242646/244766#244766).

```
gvim original.file +'vert diffpa the.patch'
```

This will open GVim and split the window, with the original on the left and the patch applied on the right.  You can then add, remove, or change hunks, and save the changes.  (Well, if you want to create a `new.patch` you'll have to run `diff` again, but that's not difficult.)

Answer (score 8):

You may use the [emacs ediff mode](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/ediff_2.html).
It lets you see and validate each chunk interactively.
For what it's worth, I have this handy script in my ~/bin directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "--text" ] ; then shift; fi
if diff --brief $1 $2 ; then 
exit 0 
else
emacs -fn 8x13bold --eval '(ediff-files "'$1'" "'$2'")'
fi
```

Comment: Yup. Agreed. I spent slightly too long trying kompare... Conclusion? Just use emacs. Make sure you have the menu turned on so you can see the per mode menu, open up the diff file and and use the diff mode menu. In some circumstances you may need to add the -p1 patch option to the options flags.... but if you have a failure it will tell you about the options variable.

Answer (score 4):

Another option: if you use Eclipse, you can generate and apply patches visually.

Comment: More specifically: Right click in the project explorer; choose Team->Apply Patch.

Answer (score 1):

The idea with visual diff tools is that you can:

1. make a backup copy of the patched file (or a new pristine checkout of the whole tree)
2. apply the patch
3. use the visual diff tool to review the changes in context
4. make any desired change to the patched file within the visual diff tool.

Some tools, such as meld or diffuse will automatically diff against the previous committed version of the files.

The key insight is that you CAN apply the patch, they discard everything you don't like as long as you have a backup copy, or if you are working on a clean checkout.

If you feel more comfortable with reading and modifying unified diffs, and just want to have more context for the diff, emacs has a fairly unique feature, which is [next-error-follow-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation-Mode.html) while viewing a diff file (diff major mode). That shows the context of a diff line in the target file.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use [GitExtensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) (.NET and Mono) which also supports applying patches interactively. I hope you are already familiar with git.

Edit: Everything mentioned below this line doesn't seem to be available directly in KDiff3. And as I mentioned before: I haven't tried it yet.

GitExtension normally uses KDiff3 as diff tool, which is able to view patches.

http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/kpart.html

Using it for patches it has only a two window view, (edit) and doesn't support merging :( but it also supports 3 way diff on complete folders etc.

Actually I never tryed it with patches.

Comment: How do you open an orig file plus a patch in KDiff3?

Comment: I will really appreciate if you can answer previous comment!

Answer (score 1):

On platforms where Kompare (a fairly nice piece of software if KDE is your cup of tea), I agree that Eclipse is a great option.

I have consistently been a reluctant Eclipse user AND I am consistently impressed by how well the tools work (once the platform finally starts up).

On Fedora, I've got just about every front end installed for each of the main version control engines (SVN - also serving my Windows machines, Mercurial, git, etc.);
Meld is quite nice (no patch interface though).
Submerge works well also.
But since Eclipse does know how to apply patches and Working Copy project created itself once I figured out to create the project in the folder containing my working copy, it may become my favorite SVN front end.

Comment: Update: I've just installed kdesvn and connected it to my working copy of wxWidgets... It took quite some time (at a very low priority) for kdesvn to retrieve and cache every single log for the history of the project without asking for my preferences on that action (the default is to retrieve logs on Open). Hmmm - Is this lunacy or could Mercurial improve responsiveness with type of mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Does [`xxdiff`](http://furius.ca/xxdiff/) do what you are looking for?

Answer (score -5):

I'd use meld.

Create two copies of the files, one without and another with the patch. Use meld to compare them, and you can see exactly what the patch is changing and make changes as necessary.

Seriously, why is this so hard?

Comment: Because this isn't what was asked for. If the patch will not merge correctly then there will not be a clean version to diff against.

Comment: The OP, like me when I found this question, was looking for a way to interactively apply the patch, likely because some hunks get rejected when being applied automatically.