# Highlight changed lines and changed bytes in each changed line

Tags: git, vim, diff, highlight, word-diff

Open Source project [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) has an excellent diff highlighter — it highlights changed lines **and changed bytes in each changed line!** See [here](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/changeset/12148) or [here](http://trac.gajim.org/changeset/297ad7711d20bfee1491768640d9bc5384464363) for examples.

Is there way to use the same color highlight (i.e. changed lines **and changed bytes too**) in bash terminal, `git`, or `vim` **for diff output (patch-file)?**

Comment: What is it that you want to highlight? Do you want a diff tool that higlights the byte changes? (that would be very helpful). You say vim, to my recollection vim does a lot of color manipulation already when you are using programming language templates (and other). How would you change that? There are quite a few techniques available to change color on a terminal window that is defined VT100 (and there are dozens of other definitions that will also support color escape sequences). More specifics please. Or read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100 and related links. Maybe that can help.

Comment: I know you are only interested in open source tools, and only in terminal.  But just as a reference point you may want to look at slickedit's diffzilla.  of the few diff tools I used it has always seem to best represent character differences (though it definitly had issues when the diffs where complex (combination of formatting and code changes, which is always a bad idea)

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231759/how-can-i-visualize-per-character-differences-in-a-unified-diff-file

Comment: Note: GitHub now offers such a diff tool in its Web GUI: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25723584/6309

Comment: I have posted 'yet another' pure git, diff-highlight based solution with tutorials to easily 1) find the relevant diff-highlight file, 2) make it executable 3) set necessary params in .gitconfig. Please have a look. Instructions are for Ubuntu 18.04 but should work broadly on linux systems.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19317/can-less-retain-colored-output and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/how-to-colorize-output-of-git and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278577/how-to-improve-gits-diff-highlighting and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458237/git-pretty-format-colors

Answer (score 79):

The [`diff-highlight` Perl contrib script](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight) produces output so similar to that of the Trac screenshots that it is likely that Trac is using it:

[image: screenshot of diff-highlight in use]

Install with:

```bash
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/fd99e2bda0ca6a361ef03c04d6d7fdc7a9c40b78/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight && chmod +x diff-highlight
```

Move the file `diff-highlight` to the `~/bin/` directory (or wherever your `$PATH` is), and then add the following to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```ini
[pager]
    diff = diff-highlight | less
    log = diff-highlight | less
    show = diff-highlight | less
```

Single copy paste install suggested by @cirosantilli:

```bash
cd ~/bin
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/fd99e2bda0ca6a361ef03c04d6d7fdc7a9c40b78/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight
chmod +x diff-highlight
git config --global pager.log 'diff-highlight | less'
git config --global pager.show 'diff-highlight | less'
git config --global pager.diff 'diff-highlight | less'
git config --global interactive.diffFilter diff-highlight
```

Comment: This. This is excellent. Thank you. It seems to be a little bit conservative in some places though, missing some lines that obviously have a majority of text in common. Do you have a bug tracker for it?

Comment: Ah, this is part of core git now: https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight

Comment: @s1n4: please add your explanation here also. Its the best answer.

Comment: Github's raw urls appear to have changed, so the curl command above needs to be updated to point to the [current url](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight) or use the -L tag to follow the redirect header.

Comment: It's now been turned into a module, and I think the easiest version to download from is the one immediately before that change at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/fd99e2bda0ca6a361ef03c04d6d7fdc7a9c40b78/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight

Comment: Not only is this part of core git, it's distributed with git and probably already on your system. I added details on how to enable it in my answer below. ↓

Comment: Here's the [direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54240819/241211) to @CoryKlein's answer.

Comment: This misses the diffs you see via `git add -p`. Please also add: `git config --global interactive.diffFilter diff-highlight`

Comment: Most distros have [`diff-so-fancy`](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy#install) in their repo, which uses `diff-highlight`.

Comment: One may need to run `make` in `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight` to get `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight` (see [this](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c977dbc8180892af42d7ab9235fd3e51d6c4078#diff-85dd20b8c447c2408077fd572f07370d229729275f993f9a7230be05cb0a1112) commit)

Answer (score 60):

While using `git diff` or `git log` and possibly others, use option `--word-diff=color` (there are also other modes for word diffs BTW)

Comment: `--word-diff=color` is really better (especially with `git config color.diff.old "red reverse"` and `git config color.diff.new "green reverse"`), but it is not what I want :(

Comment: So only thing you are missing is marking in colour/somehow both changed lines and bytes on same time?

Comment: I want to highlight changed lines and changed bytes in each changed line, like in Trac. Not just changed bytes, it is not the same.

Comment: You can also use this with `git add --patch`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873882/how-to-use-color-words-with-git-add-patch

Comment: The advantage of `diff-highlight` is that it works well for both word diffs and line diffs.

Comment: If you enable `diff-highlight` it automatically highlights *byte* differences in all git patch diffs. Details in my answer below. ↓

Answer (score 32):

[`diff-so-fancy`](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy) is a `diff`-highlighter designed for human eyeballs.

It removes the leading `+`/`-` which are annoying for cut/paste and makes clear sections between files.

Coloured `git` (left) vs `diff-so-fancy` (right - note the character-level highlights):

[image: diff-so-fancy output]

If you want the[`diff-so-fancy`](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy) (right side) output but not constrained to files in a `git` repository, add the following function to your `.bashrc` to use it on any files:

```bash
dsf() { git diff --no-index --color "$@" | diff-so-fancy; }
```

Eg:

```bash
dsf original changed-file
```

#### Character level highlighting and standard `diff` format

If you don't like the non-standard formatting of `diff-so-fancy`, but still want character-level `git` highlighting, use [`diff-highlight`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15149253/5353461) which will take `git`'s output and produce the really pretty standard `diff`-format output:

[image: diff-highlight screenshot]

To use it by default from `git`, add to your `.gitconfig`:

```ini
[color "diff-highlight"]
  oldNormal = red bold
  oldHighlight = red bold 52
  newNormal = green bold
  newHighlight = green bold 22

[pager]
  diff = diff-highlight | less -FRXsu --tabs=4
```

The `[pager]` section tells `git` to pipe its already colourised output to `diff-highlight` which colourises at the character level, and then pages the output in less (if required), rather than just using the default `less`.

Comment: This is very interesting, could you explain a bit about these `gitconfig` options?

Comment: Updated, also adding function `dsf()`.

Comment: Most distros have this package in their repo: https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy#install.

Answer (score 17):

A utility for byte-based diffs has been distributed with official Git since v1.7.8<sup>1</sup>. You just have to locate where it is installed on your machine and enable it.

#### Find where Git is installed

- MacOS with Git installed via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh): It's `/usr/local/opt/git` (later versions: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/git/VERSION`)
- Windows with [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org): Run `cd / && pwd -W` to find the install directory.
- Linux: Nerd. If you don't already know where Git is installed, then `ll $(which git)` or `locate git` should help.

#### Link `diff-highlight` to your bin directory so that your PATH can find it

```sh
GIT_HOME='/usr/local/opt/git/'  # Use the value from the first step.
ln -s "${GIT_HOME}/share/git-core/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight" \
      '/usr/local/bin/diff-highlight'
```

#### Enable it in your Git config

```sh
git config --global interactive.diffFilter diff-highlight # Use on interactive prompts
git config --global pager.diff "diff-highlight | less"    # Use on git diff
git config --global pager.log  "diff-highlight | less"    # Use on git log
git config --global pager.show "diff-highlight | less"    # Use on git show
```

<sup>1</sup> Here is the [v1.7.8 version](https://github.com/git/git/commit/927a13fe87e4b2e0edabb2f8615f0851f70fbbd8#diff-49404b1873b5e4ceb57f209c3ebd7762), but [lots of changes](https://github.com/git/git/commits/master/contrib/diff-highlight) have been made since then.

Comment: It would be good to specify in which version it started to be distributed with git. Also l'm guessing that distros will put it in PATH by default, so the symlink step won't be needed? And `which git` requires it to be in the PATH in the first place so it won't work if it's not :-)

Comment: It would be good! Feel free to add that information. And although Git does bundle `diff-highlight`, it does not actually _install_ it, so the symlink step is indeed necessary (at least on macOS). If you find that it isn't necessary for your platform, again feel free to update the answer. Meanwhile, `which git` usually does work, because Git _does_ install the `git` binary somewhere on the path.

Comment: Note that in debian unstable I needed to "compile" this file, because I just had a `.perl`. The compilation is trivial: just run `sudo make` in the `diff-highlight` directory.

Comment: This seems to imply Git for Windows will install the contrib content, but it does not. `diff-highlight` is not installed by the Git for Windows installer nor is there any option to do so.

Answer (score 16):

The behaviour you want is now available in git itself (as was pointed out in a comment by naught101). To enable it you need to set your pager to

```
perl /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight | less
```

where `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight` is the location of the highlighter script on Ubuntu 13.10 (I have no idea why it's in a `doc` folder). If it isn't there on your system try using `locate diff-highlight` to find it. Note that the highlighting script is not executable (at least on my machine), hence the requirement for `perl`.

To always use the highlighter for the various diff-like commands just add the following to your `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[pager]
    log = perl /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight | less
    show = perl /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight | less
    diff = perl /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight | less
```

---

I added this as a new answer naught101's comment is buried and because the set up is not quite as trivial as it should be and at least on the version of Ubuntu that I have the instructions in the [README](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight) don't work.

Comment: I've just noticed that this doesn't enable the highlighting for the diffs within `git add -p` (interactive mode). I don't know how that can be fixed though, simply adding add to the list causes it to hang.

Comment: This should work now in git 2.9.0: `git config interactive.diffFilter diff-highlight`

Comment: ^ This! Unfortunately, `diff-highlight` wasn't on my path so I had to locate it first. Details in my answer below.

Answer (score 15):

I use `--color-words` option and it works fine for me :

```
$ git diff --color-words | less -RS
```

Comment: No, this *only* shows the difference in words. What the OP (and I) want is a normal line-by-line diff, with the word differences highlighted (so, say different lines are coloured text, and the word-differences within those lines are normal coloured text, with coloured highlighting or something). See the example links now in the question.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1JrhYHRt
Actually I use vimdiff as difftool and vimdiff with molokai colorscheme to get a nice highlighting as you describe in your question.

1- git config --global diff.tool vimdiff
2- in vim ":colo molokai"

* Molokai @ https://github.com/tomasr/molokai
* Possible auto colorscheme with ~/.vimrc:

if &diff
    set background=dark
    colorscheme molokai
endif

Comment: This plus `aha` is amazing, I use it to diff file e.g. `git diff --color-words file_1.rs file_2.rs | aha --black > diff.html`

Answer (score 7):

as **@dshepherd** [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25851926/4632019):

> The behaviour you want is now available in git itself

But `diff-highlight` is located in DOC and is not available from shell.
To install `diff-highlight` into your `~/bin` directory follow next steps (This will save your typing):

```
$ locate diff-highlight
$ cd /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight  #or path you locate
$ sudo make
$ mv diff-highlight ~/bin
```

Then configure your `.gitconfig` as official doc says:

```
[pager]
    log  = diff-highlight | less
    show = diff-highlight | less
    diff = diff-highlight | less
```

**UPD**
Also you can try next on latest `git` without any installation:

```
git diff --color-words=.
```

More complex:

```
git diff --color-words='[^[:space:]]|([[:alnum:]]|UTF_8_GUARD)+'
```

Answer (score 5):

In an [answer to a similar, but slightly different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72475961/492158), I suggest using [Delta](https://github.com/dandavison/delta), which is a modern diff postprocessing tool that specifically supports the special desire for highlighting both words and lines at the same time.

Delta is highly **configurable** (with [emulation modes](https://dandavison.github.io/delta/diff-highlight-and-diff-so-fancy-emulation.html) for `diff-highlight` and `diff-so-fancy`) and includes many [features](https://dandavison.github.io/delta/features.html) not found in other tools: **side-by-side** views, **syntax highlighting**, and coloring of **merge conflicts** and **`git blame` output**.

The Delta documentation also has an [overview of related projects](https://dandavison.github.io/delta/related-projects.html) that mentions a few more ad-hoc tools that can highlight both words and lines.

[image: Delta diff formatting example]

Answer (score 2):

Emacs has the ediff-patch-buffer function which should fulfill your needs.

Open the un-patched file in emacs type ESC-x, ediff-patch-buffer.

Follow the prompts and you should see a highlighted comparison of the patched and original versions of your file.

As per your comment the following will will give you a bash solution requiring only dwdiff:

```
#!/bin/bash
paste -d'\n' <(dwdiff -2 -L -c <(cat $2) <(patch $2 -i $1 -o -)) <(dwdiff -1 -L -c <(cat $2) <(patch $2 -i $1 -o -))| uniq
```

Comment: sorry, I do not want to use emacs, only bash, git or vim

Comment: That's understandable.

The only other thing i can think of is to use colordiff with the stdout from patch: 
`colordiff -u <(patch original_file -i patch_file -o -) <(cat original_file)`

but this is only going to highlight changed lines not bites...

Comment: I gave your problem a bit more thought and have appended a second solution which requires only dwdiff.

Comment: please read carefully my question, I do not want to compare files

Comment: sorry for the confusion, so your just after a way to highlight the changed bytes on the changed lines of a diff file? if so try `dwdiff -c --diff-input diff_file`

Comment: I tried it before writing previous comment. unfortunately it does not highlight changed lines, only changed bytes :(

Answer (score 1):

**Diffy**

GitLab is using Diffy https://github.com/samg/diffy (Ruby) to achieve output similar to GitHub and diff-highlight:

[image]

Diffy makes the diff itself using the same algorithm ad Git, and supports different types of outputs, including the HTML output that GitLab uses:

```
gem install diffy
echo '
  require "diffy"    
  puts Diffy::Diff.new("a b c\n", "a B c\n").to_s(:html)
' | ruby
```

Output:

```
<div class="diff">
  <ul>
    <li class="del"><del>a <strong>b</strong> c</del></li>
    <li class="ins"><ins>a <strong>B</strong> c</ins></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note how `strong` was added to the changed bytes.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: this is a duplicate of what is found here: [How to improve git's diff highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278577/how-to-improve-gits-diff-highlighting/60970801#60970801) . Posting my answer here too though, as it may be helpful to some people who find directly this thread :)

As said in some previous answers, this is possible with only git stuff. I post this as the instructions may be a bit easier to follow depending on your system, but this is similar to several other answers.

One solution that is purely relying on git and its contribs. This requires no additional files than what comes with **git**. All explanations are for Ubuntu (tested on 18.04LTS), should work similarly on other linux systems:

- Locate the diff-highlight contrib git snippet:

```
find -L /usr -name diff-highlight -type f
```

on my system the only valid answer is:

```
/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight
```

- Make the corresponding perl script executable. In my case I needed to do:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight
```

- Update your `~/.gitconfig` to get the result you want, by adding (note these are TABS, not 4 spaces):

```
[color "diff-highlight"]
    oldNormal = red
    oldHighlight = red 52
    newNormal = green
    newHighlight = green 22
```

- Enjoy the result (note: this is only for the diff coloring + highlight, I have other things at play here too for the prompt of course :) ).

[image: diff-highligh]

Answer (score 0):

My vim plugin [vim-gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) does this when you preview a diff.  You can see a simple example in the screenshot in the readme.

The code that calculates the intra-line differences is [here](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/blob/master/autoload/gitgutter/diff_highlight.vim).

Answer (score 0):

Some of the tools may already mentioned but I will try to summarise and add some extra tips here:

### Bash/Terminal

You can use the `colordiff` or `diff-so-fancy`

#### Install

Pick depending on your system

```
sudo apt-get install colordiff
# or
sudo yum install colordiff
```

#### Usage

```
colordiff firstFile secondFile
# or for word coloring
colordiff -y firstFile secondFile
```

### Git

In case your diff not already highlight the output this can configured with:

```
git config --global color.ui auto
git config --global color.diff.wordDiff true
```

### Vim

Vim has a build-in highlighting that can be enabled via editing the `~/.vimrc` and adding the following lines:

```
syntax enable
filetype plugin indent on
```

For highlighting the exact bytes it is required an extra plugin there are multiple plugins available for this purpose ie `diffchar.vim` or `vim-gitgutter`

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Vim does this including the highlighting of text changed within a line.
See `:h diff` and `:h 08.7` for more details on how to diff files.

Vim uses a fairly simple algorithm for it's highlighting.
It searches the line for the first changed character, and then the last changed character, and simply highlights all characters between them.
This means you can't have multiple highlights per line - many design decisions in Vim prioritise efficiency.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not highlight changed bytes on diff output (set filetype=diff)

Comment: I think I understand your question now - You want to syntax highlight the textual output of the diff command so that it highlights any changes made inside of a line. Editing this text in Vim highlights line differences, but not the changes made within a line.

Comment: Could you use Vim's :patchfile command to load the original file and then compare it to the patched version?

Comment: unfortunately no, I want to use recursive diff output for multiple files