# Can I make git add -p show changes like git diff --word-diff?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-patch

I have recursively replaced many single word patterns in my code base. Before committing I need to check each for false replacements. It would help me a lot to have `git add -p` use the format of what `--word-diff` uses with `git diff`, where only the changed words are marked and not the entire line.

Someone has asked the same here, but maybe it was implemented since?
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-users/7uO2OUJGvP0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use --color-words with git add --patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873882/how-to-use-color-words-with-git-add-patch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Git 2.9, you can use the property [`interactive.diffFilter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-interactivediffFilter) (as I mentioned below [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37817331/6309))

But, any `git -c interactive.diffFilter="git diff --color-words" add -p` would generate, since Git 2.17, an error message

```
fatal: mismatched output from interactive.diffFilter
```

(as seen [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53213708/6309))

So using a [script for the `interactive.diffFilter` setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39811744/6309) remains a safer way.

Comment: The `--color-words` example doesn't seem to work properly. It shows each chunk for staging multiple times and even when certain chunks have been rejected during interactivity, they end up being staged.

Comment: @dionyziz What version of git are you using?

Comment: I am using git version 2.13.3.

Comment: @dionyziz Does it persists with the latest 2.15?

Comment: Doesn't work at all with git 2.19. `fatal: mismatched output from interactive.diffFilter` `hint: Your filter must maintain a one-to-one correspondence between its input and output lines`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout True, that is now enforced since Git 2.17 (https://stackoverflow.com/q/53213708/6309). I have amended the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `diff-highlight` to the `interactive.diffFilter` config key is the easiest option (since Git 2.9). The following comand does the trick on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
git config interactive.diffFilter "perl /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight"
```

Things like `git -c interactive.diffFilter="git diff --color-words" add -p` or `git config interactive.diffFilter "git diff --color-words"` don't work properly: `add -p` always keeps suggesting the first modified file.

Comment: This works quite well (although it doesn't look quite as nice as `git diff --word-diff`).