# `git config interactive.diffFilter diff-highlight`: the same diff by lines - and without color

Tags: git, git-diff, git-difftool

After `git config --global interactive.diffFilter diff-highlight` my `.gitconfig`:

```
# This is Git's per-user configuration file.
[user]
    name = Vitaly Zdanevich
    email = vitaly.zdanevich@xxx.com
[core]
    excludesfile = /Users/vitaly/.gitignore_global
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge --skip -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process --skip
    required = true
[diff]
    tool = vimdiff
    context = 20
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[interactive]
    diffFilter = diff-highlight
```

But in `git commit -p` and `git add -p` I see the same diff line-by-line **without color** in default `terminal.app`:

[image: git config interactive.diffFilter diff-highlight git diff without color]

Also I tried:

`git -c interactive.diffFilter="git diff --color-words" add -p`

And get:

```
fatal: mismatched output from interactive.diffFilter
hint: Your filter must maintain a one-to-one correspondence
hint: between its input and output lines.
```

My git version is `2.17.2 (Apple Git-113)` on `macOS 10.14.1` from the official Command Line Tools, I prefer simplicity so not from the Brew.

Comment: They made changes in git which also broke `diff-so-fancy` in interactive `add`: https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy/issues/296 .

Comment: A workaround is presented here: https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy/issues/35#issuecomment-578188120

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like fixed with new git version (2.26.2)

[image: git diff-highlight]

Answer (score 2):

Even though Git 2.26 helps, I would still recommend a more recent version of Git.

Those who use `diff-so-fancy` as the diff-filter noticed a regression or two in the code that parses the diff output in the built-in version of "`add -p`", which has been corrected with Git 2.38 (Q3 2022).

See [commit 0a10167](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0a101676e58481f134353ee1ff3ccee6cbbbb74b), [commit fd3f7f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd3f7f619aa97ce577b29a19cfd056e20680f62a), [commit b6633a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b6633a005384a8c120d34a8a79a5a5fe9d8719d7) (01 Sep 2022) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fb094cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fb094cb583e9e0f3842a6c445ccf84455cf17136), 09 Sep 2022)</sup>

> ### [`add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd3f7f619aa97ce577b29a19cfd056e20680f62a): gracefully handle unparseable hunk headers in colored diffs
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Philippe Blain</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Phillip Wood</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> In [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/ecf6f5be-22ca-299f-a8f1-bda38e5ca246@gmail.com), Phillipe Blain reported that the built-in [`git add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fd3f7f619aa97ce577b29a19cfd056e20680f62a/Documentation/git-add.txt#L96)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--p))</sup> command fails when asked to use [`diff-so-fancy`](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy) to colorize the diff.
>
> The reason is that this tool produces colored diffs with a hunk header that does not contain any parseable `@@ ... @@` line range information, and therefore we cannot detect any part in that header that comes after the line range.
>
> As proposed by Phillip Wood, let's take that for a clear indicator that we should show the hunk headers verbatim.
> This is what the Perl version of the interactive `add` command did, too.

And:

> ### [`add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0a101676e58481f134353ee1ff3ccee6cbbbb74b): ignore dirty submodules
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> Thanks to always running `diff-index` and `diff-files` with the `--numstat` option (the latter with `--ignore-submodules=dirty`) before even generating any real diff to parse, the Perl version of [`git add -p`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0a101676e58481f134353ee1ff3ccee6cbbbb74b/Documentation/git-add.txt#L96)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--p))</sup> simply ignored dirty submodules and does not even offer them up for staging.
>
> However, the built-in variant did not use that flag because it tries to run only one `diff` command, skipping the unneeded `diff-index`/`diff-files` invocation of the Perl variant and therefore only faithfully recapitulates what the Perl code does once it *does* generate and parse the real diff.
>
> This causes a problem when running the built-in `add -p` with `diff-so-fancy` because that diff colorizer always inserts an empty line before the diff header to ensure that it produces 4 lines as expected by `git add -p` (the equivalent of the non-colorized `diff`, `index`, `---` and `+++` lines).
> But [`git diff-files`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0a101676e58481f134353ee1ff3ccee6cbbbb74b/Documentation/git-diff-files.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-files))</sup> does not produce any `index` line for dirty submodules.
>
> The underlying problem is not even the discrepancy in lines, but that `git add -p` presents diffs for dirty submodules: there is nothing that *can* be staged for those.
>
> Let's fix that bug, and teach the built-in `add -p` to ignore dirty submodules, too.
> This *incidentally* also fixes the `diff-so-fancy` problem ;-)