# Use `git add -p` with `git diff --word-diff`

Tags: git, diff

I want to be able to use `git add -p` and have word-level changes highlighted as I inspect each hunk.

This has been a longstanding issue, but I'm still unable to find a solution.

[One answer from 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44219231/1563507) suggests using:

`git -c interactive.diffFilter="git diff --word-diff" add -p`

However, for me this produces an error:

```
fatal: mismatched output from interactive.diffFilter
hint: Your filter must maintain a one-to-one correspondence
hint: between its input and output lines.
```

I can't see why the output of `git diff --word-diff` would create a mismatch with the needs of `git add -p`.

In fact, I can even do this:

`git -c interactive.diffFilter="git diff" add -p`

And I get the same error -- despite the filter being the plain unflagged `git diff` command itself.

I can only think that lines are being added or removed as part of the filter addition itself, or maybe the paging of `git diff` (showing as many hunks at once, rather hunk by hunk) is the problem?