# `git add --patch` with `--word-diff`

Tags: git, git-diff, git-config, git-add, ergonomics

`git add --patch` provides a great interface for reviewing unstaged changes and then staging only the ones that are wanted in the next commit.

Great, except for one thing: there is no obvious way to choose which `diff` view to use.

In particular, I would like to be able to configure `git add --patch` to present diffs to me the same way that `git diff --word-diff` does.

How can I achieve that?

*(N.B. neither `--word-diff` nor `--word-diff --color` is exactly the same as `--color-words`, and so this question (and its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49059282)) are different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873882/how-to-use-color-words-with-git-add-patch) and its answers. However, that question's answers are much more comprehensive than this one's, so that is probably the place to go for more information about how to do achieve things **like** this.)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use --color-words with git add --patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873882/how-to-use-color-words-with-git-add-patch)

Comment: @phd, thanks. It is similar, but not the same. I have now clarified this.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278577/how-to-improve-gits-diff-highlighting/60970801#60970801 . Please give a look at the answers there.

Answer (score 7):

This is sort of possible, as follows:

```
git -c interactive.diffFilter="git diff --word-diff --color" add --patch
```

However, what Git shows you, and what will actually be staged as a result of your interactive commands, [will not necessarily match](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=151998760026925&w=2).

Comment: This no longer works in `git 2.17+` and fails with ```fatal: mismatched output from interactive.diffFilter
hint: Your filter must maintain a one-to-one correspondence
hint: between its input and output lines.
```

Comment: @OlivierLeFloch, I understand this to be a stop-gap measure to avoid the silent introduction of errors. In the long run, of course, a means to achieve an error-free `git add --patch --word-diff` would be very desirable.

Comment: I actually worked on this some more and detailed a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52231087/163677 using `interactive.diffFilter` and `diff-highlight`.