# Does Github have a view that shows diffs between file versions?

Tags: github, diff, revision-history

I'm looking for a view that highlights changes to files, similar to the changes you can see viewing the Edits button for an SO item, or the history of a wiki page.

Comment: Note: the GitHub diff view now even offers diff at the word level (not just at the line level). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25723584/6309).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/c89bf2e9bcfc1bca62e36dee2d78a48f8c38c15c

You are looking for 'diffs' aka 'changesets'.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I was looking at files, and wishing I could see the revisions to a single file. Looking at the changeset view should work.

Comment: how can you accomplish this for a single file? for instance, see the global history of all changes to only a single file (not caring about other files changed during a commit).

Answer (score 1):

Note: the change set view not only offer a diff (line by line or [side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25657797/6309)), it now (Sept. 4th 2014) offer a **word-by-word diff**.

See:

### "[Better Word Highlighting in Diffs](https://github.com/blog/1885-better-word-highlighting-in-diffs)"

> Commits, compare views, and pull requests now highlight individual changed words instead of the entire changed section, making it easier for you to see exactly what’s been added or removed.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/917945/4137704/c79d41de-3389-11e4-9730-434b99d7e8f8.gif]

Answer (score 0):

See also [comparing commits across time](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/).