# diff tool with extra highlighting

Tags: diff

GitHub's diff viewer has a nice feature that it has extra highlighting on changed lines. For example, in this diff, just a single word was inserted:

[image]

Are there other tools that display a diff like this? Pastebin's diff viewer and http://www.quickdiff.com/ don't do this, and even GitHub's gist doesn't do this if you tell it to highlight a .diff file.

I'd like some way to take two files or the output of diff and show this nice output without having to put it on GitHub. Does anything exist?

Comment: Note: the GitHub diff is now at the word level: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25723584/6309.

Answer (score 0):

[Kompare](http://www.kde.org/) is able to highlight differences in a viewed patch, although it displays the file content in two different panes and not line over line like in your picture.

[image: Screenshot of kompare]

---

For diffing with highlighting I like [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) better, but it will require two files to compare, it does not operate directly on patch files like kompare can.

[image: Screenshot of KDiff3]

Comment: Can it export the diff into a format I can send to someone else?

Comment: Not directly. But both supports printing, so printing to a pdf file is possible if that is an acceptable solution.