# Change github diff to be side by side comparison?

Tags: git, github

For github web browsing, it is not shown as side by side as lots of diff tool does. Can I change the diff mode to side by side? I mean on the github web.

Comment: **It is possible since Sept. 3rd, 2014**: See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25657797/6309)

Comment: It is hidden behind the cog wheel ⚙ symbol (right to "Conversations").

Answer (score 81, accepted):

2023: It is hidden behind the cog wheel ⚙ symbol (right to "Conversations").

---

2014:

Yes, it is possible since Sept. 3rd 2014: see "[**Introducing split diffs**](https://github.com/blog/1884-introducing-split-diffs)":

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/98681/4139311/699ef6da-3399-11e4-8d8e-cf0a9e902867.gif]

> Diffs now come in two flavors, unified and split.
> Switch between them on pull request, commit, and compare pages using the toggle in the top right of the page.
> The mode you last used will become your preferred default.

---

Note: since Sept. 4th 2014, it also support **word diff highlights**.
See "[Does Github have a view that shows diffs between file versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25723584/6309)".

---

Since 2014, and the introduction of dark theme(!) in 2020, the UI is now:

- from Unified:

[image: unified]

- To split diff:

[image: split diff]

using: [image]

Note: adding "`&diff=split`" at the end of the URL will give you the same result: a split diff.

Comment: Any idea why I wouldn't be seeing this?  Instead of "unified" and "split" buttons, I see "Show diff stats".

Comment: @Marty do you have an url?

Comment: The functionality has since been hidden behind the cogwheel next to all commits / file filter / jump to

Answer (score 26):

Seems it has been moved. (At least when reviewing PR files)

[image]

Comment: This is the current correct answer, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: no longer relevant. [Octosplit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/octosplit/mnkacicafjlllhcedhhphhpapmdgjfbb/reviews%20Octosplit%20Chrome%20extension) now says "WARNING : No longer relevant with GitHub’s built-in side-by-side diff."

---

You can with [Octosplit Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/octosplit/mnkacicafjlllhcedhhphhpapmdgjfbb/reviews%20Octosplit%20Chrome%20extension).  But you don't get the full length of the file.

Comment: Don't get the full length of what?

Comment: full length of the file

Comment: Please [edit] to add the info from your comment to your answer itself.

Comment: Doesn't matter. https://github.com/KuiKui/Octosplit now says "WARNING : No longer relevant with GitHub’s built-in side-by-side diff."

Comment: this answer doesn't address OP at all

Comment: It did back in 2013. Why are we still keeping this thread alive? GitHub has had side-by-side diff for ages now.  End of story.

Answer (score 2):

Not `git diff`, but you can use `git difftool`, which will call appropriate utility for your platform to do just what you are asking for.

For example, in Linux it will call `meld` by default, which is very nice tool. `git difftool` knows about quite a few diffing utilities, but you can also configure it to call your own.

Comment: I mean when I directly on the web site, how to change the diff?

Comment: hmm, I have not seen this req in original question - you must have edited it since. I frankly don't know how - you should ask Github customer support...

Answer (score 2):

Github web does not have the feature yet.

You might be interested in term based diff tool [ydiff](https://github.com/ymattw/ydiff), it has an option `-s` to yield side-by-side diff.

To view changes not submitted yet, type

```
ydiff -s
```

To view change history in your workspace, type

```
ydiff -ls
```

To view changes from a pull request, pipe in the raw diff from the url, for example:

```
curl https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/ymattw/ydiff/pull/11.diff | ydiff -s
```

Comment: FWIW, I fixed the cdiff references, but I'm not sure if I fixed your curl example correctly... please validate

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not possible on GitHub at the moment. You can check out other on-line diff tools, such as: http://www.quickdiff.com/, http://www.diffchecker.com/ and http://www.diffnow.com/. These will give you side-by-side diffs, but you have to copy/paste text manually.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it can do it as of version 1.7.9:
https://raw.github.com/gitster/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.9.txt