# git diff with combined --word-diff

Tags: git, git-diff

Given a file with a single word changed, a "normal" `git diff` looks like this:

[image: normal git diff]

Whereas a `git diff --word-diff=color` looks like this:

[image: git diff with --word-diff]

Is it possible to combine the two to get separate lines with the changed words highlighted? Something like this:

[image: combined git diff]

It might be trivial, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/15149253/1860929 which is available at https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight

Answer (score -3):

The links in the comments shows ways to use extensions and 3rd party to do it.

There is a simple way by adding colors in your git config file. for example

```
[color "diff"]
    meta = yellow bold
    frag = magenta bold
    old = red
    new = magenta green
```

Of course you can set any supported color to your needs.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't highlight changed words separately, does it?

Comment: The colors scheme i pasted here will highlight the words in the colors you choose to set. simply add it to your .gitconfig and play with the colors to get the desired result.

Comment: `git diff --color-words` concatenates the changes (see my 2nd screenshot). I'd like to have two separate lines for each change (just like in `git diff`), but with the changed words / characters highlighted. `git diff` does not seem to support this combined output, choosing different colors doesn't change that. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, now i fully understood what  you want, i didn't understand that you want 2 lines with word highlight. ill be back in few hours and ill test my idea and post it

Comment: I'm going to guess that it didn't work?