# gitlab highlighting whole line instead of just the characters changed in a long string

Tags: git, gitlab

Not sure if this is in general the git thing or gitlab, but I don't like it highlighted a rather long sub-section of a long continuous string in deeper colour including parts that were not changed when only some characters are changed in the string.

Is there a way to configure gitlab not to do this? i.e. just highlights those characters updated only

e.g. this is what I got on gitlab 8.10

[image]

and I expect it to hightlight only the '2' between 't' and 'i' and highlight the 'g' between 'm' and 'a'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature was introduced in [Gitlab 8.10](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/07/22/gitlab-8-10-released/) (see section "Inline Diffs").

`git` itself uses line-based diffs, so it will internally always store the complete changed lines. However, git tools also allow to *visually highlight* only those changed parts, e.g. with [`git diff --word-diff=color`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326008/highlight-changed-lines-and-changed-bytes-in-each-changed-line).

**Edit**

What Gitlab 8.10 introduces are additional highlights in changed lines. I.e. the complete changed lines will be highlighted with a light green/red, and the actual changes within a line will be highlighted with a darker green/red.
This is what you see in your figure:

[image: word based diff 1]

and in the figure of Gitlab's release notes:

[image: word based diff 2 gitlab]

Apparently, Gitlab highlights the largest part of the line that contains any changes. It does not try to produce minimal changes, probably due to performance reasons.

The git `--word-diff=color` option (including `gitk`'s `Markup words` and `Color words` setting) do produce fewer highlights. Compare Gitlab's diff:

[image: word based diff 3 gitlab]

with the same diff from `gitk`:

[image: word based diff 3 gitk]

However, even `--word-diff=color` will—as the name suggests—only highlight on a word-by-word basis. For your example, it will simply highlight both words. Here is your case reproduced in `gitk` with `Color words`:

[image: word based diff 1 gitk]

For the command line tools (e.g. `git diff`), there is actually an option `--color-words=.` that will do what you want:

[image: char based diff 1]

However, neither `gitk` nor Gitlab know this option, as far as I know.

Comment: Sorry I had to unpick yours as the answer because I was just on 8.10 and still it is not highlighting only those changed, unless there is an option or config to turn that on that I dont know.