# Git pager set to diff-highlight does not work in Windows 10

Tags: windows, git, pager

I have set Git's pager option to this

```ini
[pager]
    log = diff-highlight
```

I downloaded the `diff-highlight` script from [Git's repository `3dbfe2b8`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3dbfe2b8ae94cbdae5f3d32581aedaa5510fdc87/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight) and placed it in my `~/bin` folder.

```
$ where git
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
$ where diff-highlight
C:\Users\andy\bin\diff-highlight
```

Running `git log` results in the following error:

```
$ git log
Can't open diff-highlight: No such file or directory at C:\Users\andy\bin\diff-highlight line 36.
Segmentation fault
```

On the other hand, the following command runs just fine,

```
$ git log -p --color | diff-highlight | less -FRSX
```

This means `diff-highlight` is available from `$PATH`, but Git's config cannot find it.

My Git version is `2.12.0.windows.1`.

Comment: I tried this today by copying `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight` from Linux side to a Windows directory in PATH and it worked okay.  my git version: 2.33.1.windows.1

Answer (score 2):

[Recent guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54240819/241211) suggests putting the whole `diff-highlight | less -FRSX` string into the `pager.XXX` config.

This works just fine for me with a `Make`d version of the current `diff-highlight` script, although I only use it for `pager.diff` and `interactive.diffFilter`.

Comment: Future visitors: I now use [`delta`](https://github.com/dandavison/delta) as my pager instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `Segmentation fault` part should, at least, disappear: When a non-existent program is given as the pager, we tried to reuse an uninitialized `child_process` structure and crashed, which has been fixed with Git 2.35 (Q1 2022).

See [commit f917f57](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f917f57f40a22b64ab5354e99dbf32bb48d9fc0a) (24 Nov 2021) by [Enzo Matsumiya (`ematsumiya`)](https://github.com/ematsumiya).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bb47eee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb47eee9df438ea1934effb1fb8877deb4852821), 10 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pager`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f917f57f40a22b64ab5354e99dbf32bb48d9fc0a): fix crash when pager program doesn't exist
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Enzo Matsumiya</sup>
>
> When `prepare_cmd()` fails for, e.g., pager process setup, `child_process_clear()` frees the memory in `pager_process.args`, but `.argv` was pointed to `pager_process.args.v` earlier in `start_command()`, so it's now a dangling pointer.
>
> `setup_pager()` is then called a second time, from `cmd_log_init_finish()` in this case, and any further operations using its `.argv`, e.g. `strvec_*,` will use the dangling pointer and eventually crash.
> According to trivial tests, `setup_pager()` is not called twice if the first call is successful.
>
> This patch makes sure that `pager_process` is properly initialized on `setup_pager()`.
> Drop `CHILD_PROCESS_INIT` from its declaration since it's no longer really necessary.
>
> Add a test to catch possible regressions.
>
> Reproducer:
>
> ```
> $ git config pager.show INVALID_PAGER
> $ git show $VALID_COMMIT
> error: cannot run INVALID_PAGER: No such file or directory
> [1]    3619 segmentation fault (core dumped)  git show $VALID_COMMIT
> ```