# git diff --> show changed part in the line

Tags: git, git-diff

If I execute `git diff` I see the whole line in red color.

Is there a way to highlight the change in the line?

I often have a diff where just a single line got changed.

Highlighting the change in the line would make `git diff` more convenient for me.

[image: git-diff-whole-line-red]

git version 2.32.0

This should work on the command-line (no GUI).

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800578/how-to-colorize-diff-on-the-command-line

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326008/highlight-changed-lines-and-changed-bytes-in-each-changed-line + https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're willing to use an extra tool, [delta](https://github.com/dandavison/delta) is a word-level diff highlighter that does detection of multiple changes in a single line — and also does syntax highlighting (i.e., like GitHub diffs).

[image]

If you don’t want syntax highlighting in your diffs, you may also like [diff-so-fancy](https://github.com/so-fancy/diff-so-fancy) — a great tool I used for years (but which unlike [delta](https://github.com/dandavison/delta), can’t do detection of multiple changes in a single line).

[image]

Comment: The images you shared are not inline diff though

Answer (score 45):

#### Use the `--word-diff` option for `git diff`

For example, `git diff --word-diff=color`:

[image: git-diff-word-diff-color]

and `git diff --word-diff=plain`:

[image: git-diff-word-diff-plain]

There's also `--word-diff-regex=<regex>`

See `git help diff` for more info.

Comment: If you want minimal highlighting, use `--word-diff-regex=.`, which is sometimes clearer (when changs that qualifiy as a "word" get noticeably longer than the "levels" change above, that's clear enough as-is).

Answer (score 2):

Use colordiff tool [colordiff](https://www.colordiff.org/) so you can use with the git diff to see all minor changes with color

```
yum install colordiff

# enter yout git repository
git diff --word-diff=color
```

for example in my directory the tool output the image below

[image]:

Comment: While `colordiff` is useful for non-Git usage, the command `git diff --word-diff=color` operates just with Git’s own resources, it does not use `colordiff`.