# Using an alternate diff algorithm in Git

Tags: git, diff

Because `git` is designed for source code, its default `diff` algorithm treats a line as the minimum indivisible unit.

I am trying to edit some markdown files that are word wrapped at column 80.  Adding a sentence can cause the rest of the paragraph to be marked as changed.

Is there a way to have Git use a diff algorithm more suited to text? I need one that treats words or sentences as indivisible units rather than lines?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You might try `git diff --word-diff` instead.

```
$ git diff --word-diff
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 54585bb..a8cd97e 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
Because git is designed for source code, its diff algorithms {+are bibbity +}
{+bobbity boo+} treat a line as the minimum indivisible unit. I am trying to edit 
some markdown files that are word wrapped at column 80. Adding a sentence can 
cause the rest of the paragraph to be marked as changed.

Is there a way to have Git use a diff algorithm more suited to text? One that 
treats words or sentences as indivisible units rather then lines?
 No newline at end of file
```

Comment: `--word-diff` can have an optional `<mode>` argument, as mentioned by @manojlds. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---word-diffltmodegt

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you are looking for `word-diff`

> --word-diff[=`<mode>`]
>
> Show a word diff, using the `<mode>` to
>   delimit changed words. By default,
>   words are delimited by whitespace; see
>   --word-diff-regex below. The `<mode>` defaults to plain, and must be one of:
>
> color
>
> Highlight changed words using only
>   colors. Implies --color.
>
> plain
>
> Show words as [-removed-] and
>   {added}. Makes no attempts to escape
>   the delimiters if they appear in the
>   input, so the output may be ambiguous.
>
> porcelain
>
> Use a special line-based format
>   intended for script consumption.
>   Added/removed/unchanged runs are
>   printed in the usual unified diff
>   format, starting with a +/-/
>   character at the beginning of the line
>   and extending to the end of the line.
>   Newlines in the input are represented
>   by a tilde ~ on a line of its own.
>
> none
>
> Disable word diff again.
>
> Note that despite the name of the
>   first mode, color is used to highlight
>   the changed parts in all modes if
>   enabled.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example of customising this (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483041/git-color-words-excluding)). As a default, --word-diff assumes a word to be a string of non-whitespace characters. The following command will consider a word consist of one of the following:

1. A string of alpha-numeric characters and underscores
2. A single non-character

The command:

```
git diff --color-words --word-diff-regex='[A-z0-9_]+|[^[:space:]]'
```

Comment: That last flag can be set globally: `git config --global diff.wordRegex '[A-z0-9_]+|[^[:space:]]'`.

Comment: Or [`git diff --color-words='[^[:space:]]|([[:alnum:]]|UTF_8_GUARD)+'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25634420/321973)