# Git - Color words excluding {}

Tags: regex, git

I am using git with --color-words to view my diff. In my diff, it shows that I removed

```
<b>{{ljcount}}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Changes
```

And that I added:

```
<b>{{skills_limits}}</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Changes
```

This is larger than what I would like it to be (I want the word boundary to be at the {}). I tried playing around with `--word-diff-regex`, but I couldn't find a regex to make it work. How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `git help diff`:

```
   --word-diff-regex=<regex>
       Use <regex> to decide what a word is, instead of considering runs of non-whitespace to be a word. Also implies
       --word-diff unless it was already enabled.
```

The following expression will make a word be any string of characters and underscore, or any non-whitespace character.

```
$ git diff --color-words --word-diff-regex='\\w+|[^[:space:]]'
```

Comment: You might want to use `[^{} ]`, otherwise spaces are now considered "words" (or even `[^{}[:space:]]`, though I'm not certain what regex engine is used here)

Comment: This actually makes it worse, it seems to be treating each individual letter as a word!

Comment: In that case you want to set your word regex to something like this: ``--word-diff-regex='[A-z_][A-z_]*'``

Comment: @holygeek: --word-diff-regex='[A-z_]+' is equivalent. Okay, my mistake before was using a * rather than a +. This however, cause other characters, such as commas to be hidden from the dif. Git suggests adding |[^[:space:]] to ensure that any single non-whitespace character can be counted as a word.

Comment: @Casebash thanks for the note on adding single non-whitespace character. I ran across this issue before when doing diff between mysql dump data. Now with the correct regex I can benefit from ``--color-words`` sql diff too.

Comment: Also \w is shorthand for any alphanumeric character or the underscore (but we have to escape the \)

Comment: I'm getting the same output if I drop the `\\w+`, e.g. `--word-diff-regex='\\w+|[^[:space:]]'` vs. `--word-diff-regex='[^[:space:]]'`

Also, the editing of this answer is inappropriate, as it makes it impossible to follow the comments, or figure out which revision the OP accepted.

Answer (score 9):

Since you already use `--color-words`, you don't need to supply `--word-diff-regex` separately, the first option accepts a regex:

> ```
> --color-words[=<regex>]
> ```
>
> Equivalent to `--word-diff=color` plus `--word-diff-regex=<regex>`
>   (if a regex was specified).

A regex that works particularly well for me is:

```
$ git diff --color-words='\w+|.'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `--color-words[=<regex>]`, make sure to use Git 2.32 (Q2 2021) or more recent: the word-diff mode has been taught to work better with a word regexp that can match an empty string.

See [commit 0324e8f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0324e8fc6b297c9e61745dc4e7d110780334157d) (04 May 2021) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 65c1891](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65c18913deeba4c5f0ca9488b1d8b6757ffc56e1), 14 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`word diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0324e8fc6b297c9e61745dc4e7d110780334157d): handle zero length matches
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> If `find_word_boundaries()` encounters a zero length match (which can be caused by matching a newline or using '`*`' instead of '`+`' in the regex) we stop splitting the input into words which generates an inaccurate diff.
> To fix this increment the start point when there is a zero length match and try a new match.
> This is safe as posix regular expressions always return the longest available match so a zero length match means there are no longer matches available from the current position.
>
> Commit [bf82940](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf82940dbf12f066ba42a2a03a5bb626ba22c067) ("`color-words`: enable `REG_NEWLINE` to help user", 2009-01-17, Git v1.6.2-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9847a524321afbfa6dbb08bfd9b6a0746f965578)) prevented matching newlines in negated character classes but it is still possible for the user to have an explicit newline match in the regex which could cause a zero length match.
>
> One could argue that having explicit newline matches or using '`*`' rather than '`+`' are user errors but it seems to be better to work round them than produce inaccurate diffs.