# git word diff on non-english text

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, human-readable

How to have a word for word diff on a human language text (in Chinese)?

I have some plain text in Chinese in a git repository. The text has been edited and I'd like to see which words have been added/removed. One line in the file represents a whole paragraph of text, so a simple git diff is not enough: we know that something has changed in a certain number of paragraph but we cannot see which sentences/words have changed in it.

To make matter worse, as I said, the text is in Chinese. Unlike English and other Indo-European languages, Chinese does not use spaces as a word delimiter. The whole paragraph, together with Chinese punctuation marks, makes a unified block without any space included. Thus, git diff --word-diff does not help at all.

Is there a way to have a human-readable diff between two versions of such a text in Chinese? Is there an equivalent of --word-diff for each character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post this as an answer to my own question, however, it contains only part of the solution, a pointer in the right direction. Something is still missing.

From
[How can I visualize per-character differences in a unified diff file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231759/how-can-i-visualize-per-character-differences-in-a-unified-diff-file) 
Try either command:

```
git diff --word-diff-regex=. 
git diff --color-words=.
```

Either of the two command above get me very close. However, I have 2 problems.
If I simply type the command above and look at the output in the console, I am only shown the beginning of each paragraph.  The whole line does not fit in the console and git truncates the end (i.e. most of it!).

Or if I try to redirect to a file:

```
git diff --color-words=. > diff.patch
```

and then use vim to view the file, I get some scrambled mess which looks more like binary code than anything human-readable.

Update:
I finally used this solution:

```
wget https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/plain/contrib/diff-highlight/diff-highlight --no-check-certificate 
chmod u+x diff-highlight
git diff --color=always | ./diff-highlight | less -R
```

Answer (score 1):

[icdiff](https://github.com/jeffkaufman/icdiff) can meet you need. When comparing Chinese text, this tool can show differences word by word.

Answer (score 0):

The word-by-word `diff` should work as your own answer. From the [doc](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), The relationship between `--word-diff-regex` and `--color-words` is as follows.

```
--color-words[=<regex>
  Equivalent to --word-diff=color plus (if a regex was specified) --word-diff-regex=<regex>.
```

Actually you can set the `word-diff` mode to `porcelain` to have a better view of the `diff` output in your console.

```
git diff --word-diff-regex=. --word-diff=porcelain
```

And to redirect the output to a file, you should not use `--color-words` (with default `--word-diff` as `color`), because the generated text file cannot recognize the color information encoded some way by `git diff` as the scrambled mess you got. You can just use `--word-diff-regex=.`, and the default `--word-diff` mode is `plain`.

```
git diff --word-diff-regex=. > diff.patch
```

Comment: Thanks but last I checked, I had the same problem as the one originally mentioned above: as I am dealing with multi-byte characters, I got garbled code instead of readable text.