# Git diff by character other than newline

Tags: git, git-diff

In one project I am currently working on, there is a minified JS file which, for a variety of reasons, comes from a separate project. Because it is minified, however, it does not include newlines, which means that Git diff is rendered completely useless.

Is there a way to tell `git diff` to compare based on a different character (such as <kbd>;</kbd>) instead of newline?

Comment: Yes, you can specify your own differ in the configs.  Easiest would probably be a prettyprinter.preprocessor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231759/how-can-i-visualize-per-character-differences-in-a-unified-diff-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're after, but I'll give it a try since no one else has answered.  You might try something like:

```
git diff --color-words=.
```

Then if desired you can apply a word wrap effect by typing `-S` (and press [ENTER]).

[git diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)'s `--word-diff-regex` may also be of interest to you.