# How to have git-diff ignore all whitespace-change but leading one?

Tags: git, whitespace, git-diff

In [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25634420/321973) I found the very neat

```bash
git diff --color-words='[^[:space:]]|([[:alnum:]]|UTF_8_GUARD)+'
```

which does a great job at compressing `git-diff`'s output to the essential while remaining legible (especially when adding `--word-diff=plain` for additional `[-`/`-]` and `{+`/`+}` surrounding deletions/additions). While this *does* include whitespace changes, the output does not highlight them in any noticeable way, e.g. when changing the indentation of a line of [python](/questions/tagged/python) code (which is a severe change) will show up as that line with the longer indentation (before or after), but there is no highlighting whatsoever.

How can whitespace changes be hightlighted correctly, maybe by replacing whitespace by some unicode characters such as `·`, `⇥` and `↵`, or something more close to `git diff --word-diff-regex=.`'s `{+    +}` etc but with the smarter word separation?

Comment: In case this matters, I'm currently using msys-git's git `2.6.2.windows.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative using the substitution suggested at the question's end:

```bash
git config --global core.pager 'less --raw-control-chars'
```

such that unicode symbols are displayed correctly instead of some weird `<c3>`ish output. Add the following to your git configuration:

```ini
[diff "txt"]
    textconv = unwhite.sh
```

and, lacking a [global solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34432841/321973), to `.gitattributes` something like

```bash
*.py diff=txt
```

Finally, `unwhite.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
awk 1 ORS='[7m\\n[27m\n' $1 | sed -e 's/ /␣/g' -e 's/\t/→/g'
```

*Be advised there are raw escape (`awk` fails to support `\e`) characters before the `[`s, I display the newline-indicating `\n` in [inverted colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#graphics) to differ them from literal `\n`s. This **may** fail to copy paste, in which case you may have to manually insert them. Or try your luck with a unicode symbol such as `↵` instead.*

I deviated from the original unicode symbols since they failed to display correctly on msysgit.

Answer (score 2):

The best I can get so far is

```bash
git diff --color-words='[[:space:]]|([[:alnum:]]|UTF_8_GUARD)+' --word-diff=plain
```

Note the removed `^` in front of `[:space:]`!

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't solve your problem, but I worry that Git might be working against you here. Recall that `--color-words=<regex>` is a combination of `--word-diff=color` and `--word-diff-regex=<regex>`. The `man git diff` documentation says:

> ```
>    --word-diff-regex=<regex>
>        Use <regex> to decide what a word is, instead of considering runs
>        of non-whitespace to be a word. Also implies --word-diff unless it
>        was already enabled.
>
>        Every non-overlapping match of the <regex> is considered a word.
>        Anything between these matches is considered whitespace and
>        ignored(!) for the purposes of finding differences. You may want
>        to append |[^[:space:]] to your regular expression to make sure
>        that it matches all non-whitespace characters. A match that
>        contains a newline is silently truncated(!) at the newline.
>
>        The regex can also be set via a diff driver or configuration
>        option, see gitattributes(1) or git-config(1). Giving it
>        explicitly overrides any diff driver or configuration setting.
>        Diff drivers override configuration settings.
> ```

Note this part of the middle paragraph: "***Anything between these matches is considered whitespace and ignored(!) for the purposes of finding differences.***" So, it sounds like Git trys to treat whitespace specially here, and that might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I see... So I went for [the substitution route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34653541/321973)