# How to globally apply a textconv filter to all text files?

Tags: git, text, filter, git-diff, git-filter

I know via [`gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) `diff=...` one can set files specified by a name pattern to use a `textconv` specified filter for `git-diff` et al., but is there any way to have `git-diff` use a specific diff filter for *all* files `git` determines to be text files, no matter their name, but without affecting non-text files?

Comment: I wish I could just do `git diff --textconv=path/to/script` to generate an ad-hoc different view of a diff.

Comment: @rjmunro That alone would be nice indeed. Best I might come up with might be a script parsing `git log` for the changed files, adding them to a temporary `.gitattributes` file with the `textconv` and undo that after `git diff`. And I'd probably forget to check for binary files...

Comment: You don't need the `git log`, you can use `*` in the .gitattributes folder. This means the diff is actually not that hard to do.

Comment: @rjmunro Indeed, what was I thinking? So the only problem would stem from files git would otherwise determine to be binary...