# RuntimeLibrary mismatch despite the correct flags being passed to all objects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msvcrt

I tried to link a library (let's call it `LibB`) to a program (`TheProgram`) that already linked another library (`LibA`).

The debug configuration builds fine, but in release mode I get this error:

```
error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MTd_StaticDebug' in TheProgram.obj
```

I thought that's easy to fix, because I only need to make sure that each of the linked objects are built with /MT. I did, and they all are. I also checked if there are any per-file settings that have the runtime flag differently in this configuration - there aren't. Also checked the final command line in the build - it's /MT everywhere.

Even more interestingly, if I link the debug version of `LibB` (while building the Release configuration), this error disappears, but I get other errors.

What could cause the mismatch despite the matching flags everywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This drove me crazy and took days to discover. I wanted to share this here, because there is an abundance of questions where the problem is actually mismatching /M* flags, but that was not the case here.

The mistake was that I added a new **preprocessor define** in Debug mode, then copied over the whole field to the Release configuration (not wanting to fiddle with the mouse selection). This field contained `_DEBUG` (instead of `NDEBUG`) and that caused the linker to detect that /MTd was being linked. When I changed `_DEBUG` to `NDEBUG` in the Preprocessor Definitions in Release mode, the problem was solved.

As a side note, I tried to find the error in `git diff`, because I had a pretty good idea which commit introduced it, but it was very hard to see without a word-by-word diff due to the nature of the VS project file format. One colleague spotted this define for me, but he also pointed me to this answer about [highlighting word differences in git diff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25634420/140367), I think this can be very useful to find problems like this.